# How to capture the event whenever the items inside the listview is enabled or disabled and get the number of enabled checkboxes inside the listview

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, pyqt, qgis-2.14

I have a function "openBrowse" which will allow the user to select SQL files from a local path and display the file names as with dynamic checkboxes created based on the number of files selected inside the listview. Checkboxes and file names were added successfully inside the listview. But I want to capture the event (whether the user enables or disables the checkboxes inside the listview)once the event takes place I would like to check how many checkboxes inside the listview were enabled if the count is one I want to do some function.How this can be done. Am new to PyQGIS. I had written a function for creating dynamic checkboxes with file names inside the listview.

my code is:

```
self.files = []
 def OpenBrowse(self):
    f = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self.dlg, "Select one or more files to open", os.getenv("HOME"),'.sql (*.sql)')
    for i in f:
        if i not in self.files:
            self.files.append(i)
    if f:
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        for i in f:
            item = QStandardItem('%s' %i)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)


        self.dlg.listView_4.setModel(model)
        self.dlg.listView_4.show()
```

Comment: Please improve your question based on http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After improving your question body, please also improve your question title which should be a summary of your question body.

Comment: no errors.... i need to display the enabled file

Comment: @joseph it's one of the part in the plugin but it displays the first selected file..

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for StackOverflow, under the tag `pyqt`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, I had a similar situation that I handled as below:

First I inserted CheckBox into the table as `cellWidget` item:

```
self.dlg.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,0,checkBoxItem)
```

And if it's `cellWidget` item, you can do the following:

```
selectedFields = []

for c in range(5):
    if self.dlg.tableWidget.cellWidget(c,0).isChecked():
        selectedFields.append(self.dlg.tableWidget.cellWidget(c,1).text())
```

I iterate over row in tableWidget and check the first (`0`) column's item which is a checkBox. If it's checked, I take a corresponding text from the second (`1`) column into my list, but you can use some kind of `count+=1` or just run a function there.

The main point is to kind of insert your CheckBox into `cellWidget`. I see you are using different types of data (`StandardItem` and `listview`), but if it won't be a problem for you to redesign it, the method I posted works cool if you `isChecked` method to `stateChanged` signal (or `stateChanged` combined with `isChecked`?), it will return what you want to get. Good luck.